# How to resolve "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file."?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I want to use a package that I installed with npm install in my React project. But when I import a component from the package like this in index.jsx:

```
import Header from "material-kit-react/src/components/Header/Header";
```

I am getting the following error message in the webpack builder:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/material-kit-react/src/components/Header/Header.js 63:25
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (63:25)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|     [classes.fixed]: fixed
|   });
>   const brandComponent = <Button className={classes.title}>{brand}</Button>;
|   return (
|     <AppBar className={appBarClasses}>
 @ ./client/App/Auth/Login/index.jsx 25:0-69
 @ ./client/App/Auth/index.jsx
 @ ./client/App/index.jsx
 @ ./client/index.jsx
 @ multi ./client/index webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=/__webpack_hmr&timeout=2000&overlay=false&reload=true
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
```

My webpack config looks like this:

```
const path = require('path')
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: [
            './client/index',
            'webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=/__webpack_hmr&timeout=2000&overlay=false&reload=true'
        ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.scss'],
        modules: [
            'node_modules',
        ]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.m?js(x)?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: [
                        '@babel/preset-env'
                    ]
                }
            }
        },{ test: /\.css$/, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] },{
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [{
                loader: 'style-loader'
            }, {
                loader: 'css-loader',
                options: {
                    sourceMap: true
                }
            }, {
                loader: 'sass-loader',
                options: {
                    sourceMap: true
                }
            }]
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'MyProject',
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'index.html'),
            filename: 'index.html'
        })
    ]
}
```

So this seems to be set up with the loader for .js files. How can I import this package correctly?

**EDIT:** 
When I include the material-kit-react folder like this

```
exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(material-kit-react)\/).*/,
```

in the babel-loader, the .js file seems to be found. But it seems to be interpreted incorrectly, and I get another error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/material-kit-react/src/components/CustomButtons/Button.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /Users/user1/Desktop/proj1/my-app/node_modules/material-kit-react/src/components/CustomButtons/Button.js: Unexpected token (51:4)

  49 |   });
  50 |   return (
> 51 |     <Button {...rest} ref={ref} className={btnClasses}>
     |     ^
  52 |       {children}
  53 |     </Button>
  54 |   );
    at Parser._raise (/Users/user1/Desktop/proj1/my-app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:742:17)
    at Parser.raiseWithData (/Users/user1/Desktop/proj1/my-app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:735:17)
    at Parser.raise (/Users/user1/Desktop/proj1/my-app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:729:17)
    at Parser.unexpected (/Users/user1/Desktop/proj1/my-app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:8757:16)
    at Parser.parseExprAtom (/Users/user1/Desktop/proj1/my-app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10052:20)
    at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (/Users/user1/Desktop/proj1/my-app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9602:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (/Users/user1/Desktop/proj1/my-app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9582:21)
    at Parser.parseExprOps (/Users/user1/Desktop/proj1/my-app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9452:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeConditional (/Users/user1/Desktop/proj1/my-app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9425:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeAssign (/Users/user1/Desktop/proj1/my-app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9380:21)
    at Parser.parseParenAndDistinguishExpression (/Users/user1/Desktop/proj1/my-app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10193:28)
    at Parser.parseExprAtom (/Users/user1/Desktop/proj1/my-app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9947:21)
    at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (/Users/user1/Desktop/proj1/my-app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9602:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (/Users/user1/Desktop/proj1/my-app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9582:21)
    at Parser.parseExprOps (/Users/user1/Desktop/proj1/my-app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9452:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeConditional (/Users/user1/Desktop/proj1/my-app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9425:23)
 @ ./client/App/Landing/Landing.jsx 8:0-76 31:88-94
 @ ./client/App/Landing/index.jsx
 @ ./client/App/index.jsx
 @ ./client/index.jsx
 @ multi ./client/index webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=/__webpack_hmr&timeout=2000&overlay=false&reload=true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
exclude: /node_modules/,
```

in your `babel-loader` config, so Babel will never process any files in `node_modules`, which is where `material-kit-react` is located.

Your Babel config also only has

```
'@babel/preset-env'
```

which does nothing to enable JSX support. You also need to enable

```
'@babel/preset-react'
```

Comment: when I remove the exclude: /node_modules/, line in the config file, it seems to find the file, but then it seems to interpret the file incorrectly (see my update in the question). Any ideas how to resolve this?